# Cake Cooking Time: Burning on outside - raw in the middle

Tags: baking, cake

I am doing some work in a volunteer kitchen and as part of our meals we provide cake that we bake in a big tray, we can only fit two on a rack in a commercial gas oven at a time.  Full gastronorm trays I think they are called.

All our recipes call for a temperature of 180 degrees C (356 F) 40 mins - we rotate them in the oven after 20 mins.

The depth of the cake mixture prior to baking is about 5cm (2 inches) - not unusual.

The cakes are vegan - no egg or butter, we use oil. The lack of egg would affect binding which may be relevant.  Essentially the recipes are vegan variations of a pound cake. (roughly by volume: 2 parts flour, 1 part each of oil, sugar, soy milk. Add in flavor, fruit etc. )

The problem is that by the time the cakes are cooked in the center, the outside is always burned. This seems to occur regardless of recipe to the point that our floor staff consider it normal to have to carve the burnt bits off the cake before serving.  It works - just not a good solution...

Things I have thought of:

1) Use a lower temperature - but longer time.  I don't want to go below 160 degrees or no maillard reaction (browning). But can't work out how much extra time I would need if I dropped the temperature by 10 or 20 degrees.

2) Chaining up the nameless idiot who keeps opening the oven door to see if the cakes are cooked yet. Said idiot swears that if he had an answer for number 1) then he would be able to restrain himself...

The tray size must have something to do with the problem, but I can't figure out what. I looked at the diffusion of heat - but it seems that the heat would be dominated by energy coming in from the top and bottom.

Possibly diffusion of steam?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I think I'd like to see a full recipe. 180C is a pretty normal temperature so it might be your recipe is too moist.

Comment: When was your oven calibration last checked?

Comment: You have at least two incorrect assumptions here. 5 cm before baking is not at all usual. At least home recipes are usually baked much thinner, around 1-2 cm before baking. I have not been in a commercial bakery and don't know how they do it. Also, no egg and no butter has a lot of effect not just on binding, but also on leavening, and adding soy milk and fruit makes it worse. So what you are trying to achieve is quite difficult, no wonder you are running into problems.

Comment: @rumtscho that heavily depends on the recipe.  Christmas cake is an extreme example but many cake mixes go into the tin in quite a thick layer.

Comment: @ChrisH If by Chrismas cake you are referring to what I would call a fruit cake or a type of loaf or ring cake, you are also cooking from all sides as well and reducing the effect of it being a thick layer, partially. I also think of most loaf and many ring typical cakes as being denser and moister than most sheet cakes, so better at heat transfer to the middle than a thick sheet.  That said, 5cm is not that unusual, but if uneven cooking is an issue, reduced thickness and then building layers could be a work-around.  I would definitely start by testing temperature accuracy though.

Comment: @dlb round here they're the same shape as normal cakes, i.e. usually round, sometimes square,but full of fruit and without much rise, so yes, better at transferring heat

Comment: Thankyou for the comments. To pick up on individual points- we thought the oven may be wonky - its new and potatoes wouldn't cook either, but it seems to have fixed itself.  Am pretty sure it was everyone in the kitchen opening the door of the new oven to see if it was working - which they now are bored of doing.

The recipes vary but are roughly 16 cups flour, 8 sugar, 8 oil, 8 water based liquid (soy milk, fruit juice etc)

I think @rumtscho may have hit it with my assumptions about depth. That would do it. Perhaps the recipes assume 4 trays not 3 and I have been making things too thick.

Comment: How much room is left around the trays to circulate heat? If it is a good few cm then tenting the cakes in foil the first half evens out the browning somewhat.  If very tight, one smaller tray may help.

Comment: @ChrisH I don't think I have ever baked an English Christmas cake. Here in Germany, the standard cake tin is 28 cm, and I just checked trusty baking books, old enough to not use translated US recipes, these give recipes for different base sponges which add up to about 750 ml, that would be 1.2 cm tall before baking. And people sometimes bake two layers at a time, but I haven't heard of 4 at a time. Larger recipes are baked in gugelhupfs. And note that those are fluffy well-leavened sponges, which set easily.

Comment: @rumtscho I thought about adding up some recipes here but given the way liquid mixes with flour  filling in the gaps (and sugar dissolves) I couldn't see the point. My usual mixing bowl doesn't have volume measurements either

Comment: For a vegan cake, try the Depression Cake, from an era when eggs and butter were hard to come by. The leavening is done by the baking soda and vinegar. I've never seen or made it other than chocolate (with cocoa). It's a fantastic recipe; great texture. You can google the exact recipe.

Comment: As a follow up.  Have been getting better results by using a thinner batter and more thorough mixing - the big improvement seems to be being rigorous about not opening the door.  The senior cook won't let me open the door at all until time is up - which is immensely frustrating - but seems to work

Comment: What speaks against going down to 160 or 170 °C and testing doneness with the good old wooden skewer test? 180°C is very near the temperature where sugar readily chars if provoked...

Answer (score 3):

This might have something to do with the amount of oil in your recipe. There is a lot of liquid - traditional pound cakes are traditional, but that doesn't mean that they're a good ratio.

Reduce ratio of oil to at least 1/4 and experiment from there - another factor is the type of oil that is being used. Certain types and qualities of oil have lower smoking points, and so burn at a lower temperature. I have tried recipes that use no oil (fat) whatsoever and remain successful.

Do you use any leavening agents? Baking powder/baking soda? If not, I would add 2tsp baking powder and 1/2tsp baking soda. As well as a pinch of salt.

Experiment by reducing the oven temperature to 160C or 325F, cook for an additional 15 - 20 minutes. To test done-ness, the traditional toothpick method is good (putting a toothpick into the thickest part of the cake and removing to check for crumb - crumbs mean more cooking) otherwise; if you press lightly on the surface of the dough and it 'springs' back, as well the cake should have pulled away from the outsides of the pan (I am a pastry chef and find this method most helpful).

If you continue to have difficulty, get that oven checked out.

Comment: Traditional pound cake has that 1:1:1:1 equivalence of butter, sugar, eggs, and flour but it is *EXTREMELY* important to note that it specifically calls for butter. You cannot do a direct substitution for any other type of fat and not get bad results.

The reason is simple: butter is only about 80% fat. The other 20% is split between water and other random milk solids. So by using butter, you're actually adding water and random solids, and less fat. On top of that, eggs are a "drier" binder than the soy milk.

I definitely think it's the oil.